# How to integrate Cytoscape with JanusGraph 0.2?

Tags: cytoscape, janusgraph

JanusGraph official website provides some graph visualization tools. Cytoscape is one of them. I want to visualize my graph data with Cytoscape. I have no clue how to integrate Cytoscape with JanusGraph. Can someone provide some information how to integrate Cytoscape with JanusGraph?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[GraphML](http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/) is the IO format of choice when integrating with other graph oriented tools, like visualization packages. Simple export your graph to that format as described in the [Apache TinkerPop documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_graphml_reader_writer):

```
graph.io(graphml()).writeGraph("export.xml")
```

The import that to Cytoscape 3 via the `File | Import` option. If I recall correctly, with Cytoscape 2 you needed the the [GraphML Reader](http://apps.cytoscape.org/apps/graphmlreader) installed. As with any visualization tool the size of the graph you intend to visualize will be constrained by the amount of memory that you have. So, if you have a large graph, you will like wish to [subgraph](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#subgraph-step) it for export so that you can visualize just the portion you care about.